# Docker - install nodejs only if it is not installed

Tags: docker

dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && \
    curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs && \
```

This will install nodejs every time I build. Can I install nodejs only if it is not installed?

Comment: Node will never be installed before that `RUN` command.  You might consider using a `node` image (maybe in a separate build stage) so that you don't have to manually install it.

Answer (score 1):

unless you change any of the layers above and including this one or clear docker cache installation would not be reexecuted